# Google Double Click for iOS

Tags: iphone

Currently iam working with an iPad application.I want to use Google DoubleClick to display Ads in my app.
Could any one tell me how to get iOS sdk for double click and steps to integrate this to my application . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty certain that Google's primary ad network is called AdMob and you can get the SDK from here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

I also found the below page which specifically talks about DoubleClick, but it only mentions iOS 4.0, so this might be out of date?

https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/ios/doubleclick/

I didn't know Google had at least two separate ad networks, but they have lots of tentacles the average iOS engineer wouldn't always be aware of.

Comment: Downloded the SDK from above link.But it misses these files GADAdViewController,GADDoubleClickParameters. Thanks a lot for your early response.